# Delete Item Again reappear in the List View

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView`. The issue in my `ListView` is that once I delete an item from my `ListView` and again add a new item in the `ListView` without exiting the app, it shows the deleted item in my `ListView` instead of showing the newly added item, Once I exited the app and open the app it shows the newly added item, and doesn't show the deleted item. It is related to the refresh issue, although I have used `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Why this happen, please help me to solve this out.

```
    // This is on create of Activity Class
    ArrayList<String> fileStrings = new ArrayList<String>(m_ItemCount);     
    for (int i = 0; i < m_ItemCount; i++)
    {
        fileStrings.add(NoteManager.getSingletonObject().getImageName(i));
        
        if(NoteManager.getSingletonObject().getStatusArray(i) == 1)
        {
            m_CompletedItemCount++;     
        }
    }

    // Call ListViewAdapter class that extend BaseAdapter class inside the method setListAdapter
    // Display all the items in the list view 
    m_Adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, fileStrings);
    setListAdapter(m_Adapter);      
    listView = getListView();
    
// Adapter Class

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> listItem;
    private LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity a,  ArrayList<String> d) 
    {
        activity = a;
        listItem = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
            
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return listItem.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        Button butDelete, butAdd;
    }
    
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder.butDelete = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.but_delete);   
            holder.butAdd = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.but_delete);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Delete item on click of delete item
        holder.butDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {               
                deleteItem(position);
            }
        });
        
        holder.butAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {               
                addItem(name);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }   
    
    // Add item in listView
    public void addItem(String stringName)
    {
        listItem.add(0, stringName);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    
    // delete item in listView
    public void deleteItem(int position)
    {   
        listItem.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to update the listItem with new values then call the notifyDataSetChanged(); as following

```
listItem.clear();           
listItem.addAll(ArrayList<String>);// put update ArrayList Value addAll() method
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: No its not working..instead it added two elements every time i wnat to add a new element

Answer (score 0):

What is m_ItemCount here???

Moreover you are just removing data from list..In actual,also remove it from actual position of the data. Because every time your list gets invalidate it gets previous data stored, so remove it from actual position also.

Comment: Actually before displaying item in the listView i store item in an array and at that time i incrementing the ItemCount value, so itemcount is the no of item present in the array. After that while displaying list i get each item from the array and stored in an ArrayList and pass that ArrayList to the adapter class. Yeh i remove item from the array while removing item from list.

Comment: Removing data from arrayList means which arrayList, the one i declared in the beginning.

Comment: The arrayList which sets the data in ListView,,,,

Comment: In my code the arraylist in the on create method set data in the List. Can u check my code and let me know actually what i should do. If i haven't remove from arrayList then why after exit the app and restart the app solve the problem

Comment: Ok..before displaying item in ListView i stored all the item in an array and itemCount is the no of element in an array.  After that i retrieve one by one each element fron this array and stored in my arrayList named as fileString in my code. after that i call ListViewAdpter class and pass this arraylist to this adapter class.

Comment: I uploaded a code according to my assumptions, it works fine,,,

Comment: I do the same way u do..and yes on delete of item it remove item from the list..but again when i add new item on the listView it show deleted item again in that position where i want to add new item. But as soon i exit the app and again start the app it shows the new item that i added and doesnt show the deleted item

Answer (score 0):

Use this code according to your requirement because it works for me:

```
         int m_ItemCount=10;
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

      ListView listView;
        ArrayList<String> fileStrings = new ArrayList<String>(m_ItemCount);     
        for (int i = 0; i < m_ItemCount; i++)
        {
            fileStrings.add(i+"");

            /*if(NoteManager.getSingletonObject().getStatusArray(i) == 1)
            {
                m_CompletedItemCount++;     
            }*/
        }

        // Call ListViewAdapter class that extend BaseAdapter class inside the method setListAdapter
        // Display all the items in the list view 
        ListViewAdapter m_Adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, fileStrings);
        setListAdapter(m_Adapter);      
        listView = getListView();

    // Adapter Class
}
     class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList<String> listItem;
        private LayoutInflater inflater=null;

        public ListViewAdapter(Activity a,  ArrayList<String> d) 
        {
            activity = a;
            listItem = d;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() 
        {
            return listItem.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public class ViewHolder
        {
            Button butDelete, butAdd;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView == null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
                holder.butDelete = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.but_delete);   
                holder.butAdd = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.but_add);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            // Delete item on click of delete item
            holder.butDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {           
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {               
                    deleteItem(position);
                }
            });

            holder.butAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {           
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {               
                    addItem("AA");
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }   

        // Add item in listView
        public void addItem(String stringName)
        {
            listItem.add(0, stringName);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        // delete item in listView
        public void deleteItem(int position)
        {   
            listItem.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }
```